# Create array of regexp match(multiline, javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create array of javascript's regexp match string from the text below.

```
.root
 this is root
..child 1
 this is child 1
 this is also child 1's content.
...child 1-1
 this is child 1-1

..child 2
 this is child 2
...child 2-1
 this is child 2-1
.root 2
 this is root 2
```

and desired array is below

```
array[0] = ".root
 this is root"

array[1] = "..child 1
 this is child 1
 this is also child 1's content"

array[2] = "...child 1-1
 this is child 1-1
"

array[3] = "..child 2
 this is child 2"

array[4] = "...child 2-1
 this is child 2-1"

array[5] = ".root 2
 this is root 2"
```

In Java, I can do like `^\..*?(?=(^\.|\Z))`, but in Javascript there is no `\Z`, `.` doesn't match newline character, and `$` matches newline character (not just the end of string).

How can I achieve this array?
 I use this site ( http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex ) to test regexp.

Comment: By the way, `$` will only match the end of string unless you add the `m` flag. For example, `/foo$/m` would match "foo" in "foo\nbar" but `/foo$/` would not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`text.split(/\r?\n^(?=\.)/gm)` produces the same array.

`text.match(/^\..*(\r?\n[^.].*)*/gm)` ugly, but still.

Comment: Oh, it works! I　haven't came up with using split! thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is in a single regular expression:

```
var re = /^[.][\s\S]*?(?:(?=\r?\n[.])|(?![\s\S]))/gm
var match
var matches = []
while (match = re.exec(text)) {
  matches.push(match[0])
}
console.log(matches)
```

outputs:

```
[
  ".root\nthis is root",
  "..child 1\n this is child 1\n this is also child 1's content.",
  "...child 1-1\n this is child 1-1\n",
  "..child 2\n this is child 2",
  "...child 2-1\n this is child 2-1",
  ".root 2\n this is root 2"
]
```

Some useful tricks:

- use `[\s\S]` to match *any* character
- [use `(?![\s\S])` to simulate `\Z`](http://davidchambersdesign.com/end-of-string-anchor-in-javascript-regular-expressions/)

Comment: Link is dead, here's Internet Archive's version of the page: http://web.archive.org/web/20120512092338/http://davidchambersdesign.com/end-of-string-anchor-in-javascript-regular-expressions/